# What do 0LL or 0x0UL mean?

Tags: c, constants

I am reading the [Google Go tutorial](http://golang.org/doc/go_tutorial.html#tmp_174) and saw this in the constants section:

> There are no constants like 0LL or 0x0UL

I tried to do a Google search but all that comes up are instances where people are using these constants but no explanation as to what they mean. 0x is supposed to start a hexadecimal literal but these are not characters that are possible in a hexadecimal number.

Comment: "I tried to do a Google search"... try the search term `integer constants c++ LL`. :)

Comment: I always thought of those as 'literals' and constants as variables declared as constants.

Comment: Fair enough, but I imagine the results for `integer literals c++ LL` are similar... :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

These are constants in C and C++. The suffix `LL` means the constant is of type `long long`, and `UL` means `unsigned long`.

In general, each `L` or `l` represents a `long` and each `U` or `u` represents an `unsigned`. So, e.g.

```
1uLL
```

means the constant 1 with type `unsigned long long`.

This also applies to floating point numbers:

```
1.0f    // of type 'float'
1.0     // of type 'double'
1.0L    // of type 'long double'
```

and strings and characters, but they are prefixes:

```
 'A'   // of type 'char'
L'A'   // of type 'wchar_t'
u'A'   // of type 'char16_t' (C++0x only)
U'A'   // of type 'char32_t' (C++0x only)
```

---

In C and C++ the integer constants are evaluated using their original type, which can cause bugs  due to integer overflow:

```
long long nanosec_wrong = 1000000000 * 600;
// ^ you'll get '-1295421440' since the constants are of type 'int'
//   which is usually only 32-bit long, not big enough to hold the result.

long long nanosec_correct = 1000000000LL * 600;
// ^ you'll correctly get '600000000000' with this

int secs = 600;
long long nanosec_2 = 1000000000LL * secs;
// ^ use the '1000000000LL' to ensure the multiplication is done as 'long long's.
```

In Google Go, all integers are evaluated as big integers (no truncation happens),

```go
    var nanosec_correct int64 = 1000000000 * 600
```

and there is no "[usual arithmetic promotion](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#conversions)"

```go
    var b int32 = 600
    var a int64 = 1000000000 * b
    // ^ cannot use 1000000000 * b (type int32) as type int64 in assignment
```

so the suffixes are not necessary.

Comment: Please provide an example that uses a hex literal. For example, what is 0xFEDCBA9876543210LL (notice the `LL` suffix). Is it a signed type (Clang insists it is an unsigned type)?

Answer (score 12):

There are several different basic numeric types, and the letters differentiate them:

```
0   // normal number is interpreted as int
0L  // ending with 'L' makes it a long
0LL // ending with 'LL' makes it long long
0UL // unsigned long

0.0  // decimal point makes it a double
0.0f // 'f' makes it a float
```

Answer (score 4):

`0LL` is a long long zero.

`0x0UL` is an unsigned long zero, expressed using hexadecimal notation.  `0x0UL` == `0UL`.

Answer (score 3):

`LL` designates a literal as a `long long` and `UL` designates one as `unsigned long` and `0x0` is hexadecimal for `0`. So `0LL` and `0x0UL` are an equivalent number but different datatypes; the former is a `long long` and the latter is an `unsigned long`.

There are many of these specifiers:

```
1F // float
1L // long
1ull // unsigned long long
1.0 // double
```

Answer (score 2):

+In C-like languages, those suffixes tell you the exact type.  So, for example. 9 is an `int` variable, but `0LL` is a `long long`

Answer (score -1):

Constants are expressions with a fixed value.

**Literals** are the most obvious kind of constants. They are used to express particular values within the source code of a program.

```
a = 5; //The 5 in this piece of code was a literal constant.
```

Literal constants can be classified into: integer, floating-point, characters, strings, Boolean, pointers, and user-defined literals.

```
   //Integral Numeral
        1776
        707
        -273
```

In addition to decimal numbers (those that most of us use every day), C++ allows the use of octal numbers (base 8) and **hexadecimal numbers (base 16)** as literal constants. For octal literals, the digits are preceded with a 0 (zero) character. And for hexadecimal, they are preceded by the characters 0x (zero, x). For example, the following literal constants are all equivalent to each other:

```
75         // decimal
0113       // octal
0x4b       // hexadecimal
```

All of these represent the same number: 75 (seventy-five) expressed as a base-10 numeral, octal numeral and hexadecimal numeral, respectively.

These literal constants have a type, just like variables. By default, integer literals are of type int. However, certain suffixes may be appended to an integer literal to specify a different integer type:
[image]

Unsigned may be combined with any of the other two in any order to form unsigned long or unsigned long long.

```
75         // int
75u        // unsigned int
75l        // long
75ul       // unsigned long 
75lu       // unsigned long
```