# ULL suffix on a numeric literal

Tags: c++, c

I've run across some code like this:

```
line += addr & 0x3fULL;
```

Obviously, 'U' and 'L' are not hex digits.  I'm guessing that the 'ULL' at the end of that hex numeric literal means "Unsigned Long Long"  - am I correct?  (this sort of thing is very difficult to google) if so then this is some sort of suffix modifier on the number?

Comment: C: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.4.4.1. C++: [N4700](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4700.pdf) 5.13.2 [lex.icon]. In both languages, the suffix is case-insensitive (except that `lL` and `Ll` are not permitted) and the `LL` and `U` are specified separately, so you can have any of `ull`, `uLL`, `Ull`, `ULL`, `llu`, `llU`, `LLu`, `LLU`.

Comment: Ping @TonyTannous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do 0LL or 0x0UL mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036056/what-do-0ll-or-0x0ul-mean)

Comment: It can be essential when manipulating uint64_t values. For example: my_var |= (1ull << bit_pos) may not give the expected result when bit_pos is more than 32 on some compilers, without the 'ull' suffix

Answer (score 97, accepted):

From the `gcc` [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Long-Long.html):

> ISO C99 supports data types for integers that are at least 64 bits wide ( . . . ) . To make an integer constant of type `long long int`, add the suffix `LL` to the integer. To make an integer constant of type `unsigned long long int`, add the suffix `ULL` to the integer.

These suffixes have also been added to C++ in [C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), and were already supported long long (pun intended) before that as compiler extensions.

Answer (score 35):

Yes that's correct.

- `0x` prefix makes it a hexadecimal literal.
- `ULL` suffix makes it type `unsigned long long`.

Comment: I suppose it makes the type *at least* that, but since it's the largest available type, that's probably the same thing.

Comment: You're right. I just tested it with `long long x = 0xfffffffffffful;` on Windows and it doesn't truncate - no warnings either.

Comment: All literals only specify the *minimal* desired width, with the absolute minimum being `int`. But any literal has a type that supports it, if any...

Answer (score 16):

I'm positing a new answer because I recognize that the current answers do not cite from a cross platform source. **The [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) standard dictates that a literal with `U`/`u` and `LL`/`ll` suffixes is a literal of type: `unsigned long long int`** [[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal)]

`U`/`u` is the C/C++ suffix for an unsigned integer.
`LL`/`ll` is the C/C++ suffix for a `long long` integer which is a [new type in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Integer_types) and required to have a length of at least 64-bits.

Notes:

1. The keyword `int` may be omitted if any modifiers are used, `unsigned long long` for example. So this will define `one` as an `unsigned long long int`, and any number assigned to it will be `static_cast` to `unsigned long long int`: `unsigned long long one = 1`
2. [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) marked the advent of `auto`. Which sets the variable type to the type assigned to it on declaration. For example, because `2ULL` is an `unsigned long long int` literal `two` will be defined as an `unsigned long long int`: `auto two = 2ULL`
3. [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) introduced order independent literal suffixes. Previously the `U`/`u` suffix had to preceded any size suffix. But circa [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) the suffixes are accepted in either order, so now since `3LLU` is an `unsigned long long int` literal `three` will be defined as an `unsigned long long int`: `auto three = 3LLU`

Comment: Because my mind works that way (but  I don't have C++14 to hand): I presume C++14 doesn't allow `13LUL`?

Comment: @TripeHound http://ideone.com has C++14 and it does not allow an LUL suffix: http://ideone.com/AWmW8H This seems to match the intent of: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#Explanation