# What is the >>>= operator in C?

Tags: c, obfuscation, literals, bit-shift, digraphs

Given by a colleague as a puzzle, I cannot figure out how this C program actually compiles and runs. What is this `>>>=` operator and the strange `1P1` literal? I have tested in Clang and GCC. There are no warnings and the output is "???"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2]={ 10, 1 };

    while( a[ 0xFULL?'\0':-1:>>>=a<:!!0X.1P1 ] )
        printf("?");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: it's not a single operator. It's multiple operators next to each other.

Comment: Some of those are [digraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C.2B.2B).

Comment: C uses the longest match to find tokens, so `>>>=a<:!!` is parsed linke `>> >= a < : ! !`. `>> >=` cannot occur in a valid sequence.

Comment: @Kay, no in this case: :> = ] then a[...] >> = a[...]

Comment: @Marc I don't think it can be ">> >=" because that wouldn't compile, however the above code actually compiles.

Comment: The `0x.1P1` is a hexadecimal literal with an exponent. The `0x.1` is the number part, or 1/16 here. The number after the 'P' is the power of two the number is multiplied by. So `0x.1p1` is really 1/16 * 2, or 1/8. And if you were wondering about `0xFULL` that's just `0xF`, and `ULL` is the suffix for an `unsigned long long`

Comment: C syntax -- endless material for pundits and trivia lovers, but ultimately not all that important.

Comment: The whitespace is in all the wrong places! *shakes head*

Comment: `>>>=`? Surely not Java?

Comment: This is why I'm not a C developer.

Comment: I love how an outright incorrect comment has more upvotes than the one that calls it out.

Comment: @KerrekSB What do you mean? Can't you recognize a super-downto operator?

Comment: Does your colleague have more of those puzzles?

Comment: @Olli1511 it's clearly a fabricated question from a disposable account -- likely posted by one of the answerees below.

Comment: @KerrekSB The horrible part is how much of it is ugly hacks inserted to allow for incomplete keyboards on obscure teletypes from the dawn of time and to no other purpose. Digraphs?! Really? Arrggghhhh!!!!!

Comment: @dmckee: Easy to be cynical now with our fancy tablets and second wives, but back in the day digraphs helped real people to do real work and put real bread on the table...

Comment: Why not ask your colleague instead of cheating. ;)

Comment: Excuse me, I need more coffee

Answer (score 470, accepted):

The line:

```
while( a[ 0xFULL?'\0':-1:>>>=a<:!!0X.1P1 ] )
```

contains the [digraphs](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C) `:>` and `<:`, which translate to `]` and `[` respectively, so it's equivalent to:

```
while( a[ 0xFULL?'\0':-1 ] >>= a[ !!0X.1P1 ] )
```

The literal `0xFULL` is the same as `0xF` (which is hex for `15`); the `ULL` just specifies that [it's an `unsigned long long` literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809292/ull-suffix-on-a-numeric-literal).  In any case, as a boolean it's true, so `0xFULL ? '\0' : -1` evaluates to `'\0'`, which is a [character literal](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Character_constants) whose numerical value is simply `0`.

Meanwhile, `0X.1P1` is a [hexadecimal floating point literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825824/hexadecimal-floating-constant-in-c) equal to 2/16 = 0.125.  In any case, being non-zero, it's also true as a boolean, so negating it twice with `!!` again produces `1`.  Thus, the whole thing simplifies down to:

```
while( a[0] >>= a[1] )
```

The operator `>>=` is a [compound assignment](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators) that bit-shifts its left operand right by the number of bits given by the right operand, and returns the result.  In this case, the right operand `a[1]` always has the value `1`, so it's equivalent to:

```
while( a[0] >>= 1 )
```

or, equivalently:

```
while( a[0] /= 2 )
```

The initial value of `a[0]` is 10.  After shifting right once, it become 5, then (rounding down) 2, then 1 and finally 0, at which point the loop ends.  Thus, the loop body gets executed three times.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the `P` in `0X.1P1`.

Comment: @Kay: It's the same as `e` in `10e5`, except you have to use `p` for hexadecimal literals because `e` is a hexadecimal digit.

Comment: @Kay: The hex float literals are part of C99, but [GCC also accepts them in C++ code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Hex-Floats.html). As Dietrich notes, the `p` separates the mantissa and the exponent, just like the `e` in normal scientific float notation; one difference is that, with hex floats, the base of the exponential part is 2 instead of 10, so `0x0.1p1` equals 0x0.1 = 1/16 times 2¹ = 2. (In any case, none of that matters here; any non-zero value would work equally well there.)

Comment: Minor: Certain `'\0'` is an `int` literal.  Try `printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof ('\0'), sizeof (char));`

Comment: @chux: Apparently, that [depends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars) on whether the code is compiled as C or (as it was originally tagged) C++. But I fixed the text to say "character literal" instead of "`char` literal", and added a Wikipedia link. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... I have tried `if (str.length() && str[str.length() :> != L'\\' && str<:str.length()]  != L'/')` but it gives compilation error, is something wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: Just to state: refer to section 6.4.6 from the C99 standard for the punctuator digraphs's semantics (i.e. `<:`). http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Answer (score 69):

It is some rather obscure code involving [*digraphs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C), namely `<:` and `:>` which are alternative tokens for `[` and `]` respectively. There is also some use of the [*conditional operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C). There is also a [*bit shifting operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Shift_operators), the right shift assignment `>>=`.

This is a more readable version:

```
while( a[ 0xFULL ? '\0' : -1 ] >>= a[ !!0X.1P1 ] )
```

and an even more readable version, replacing the expressions in the `[]` for the values they resolve to:

```
while( a[0] >>= a[1] )
```

Replacing `a[0]` and `a[1]` for their values should make it easy to figure out what the loop is doing, i.e. the equivalent of:

```
int i = 10;
while( i >>= 1)
```

which is simply performing (integer) division by 2 in each iteration, producing the sequence `5, 2, 1`.

Comment: I didn't run it - would this not produce `????`, though, rather than `???` as the OP got? (Huh.) http://codepad.org/nDkxGUNi *does* produce `???`.

Comment: @Jongware the 10 got divided on first iteration.  So the values being evaluated by the loop are 5, 2, 1, and 0.  So it only prints out 3 times.

Answer (score 42):

Let's go through the expression left-to-right:

```
a[ 0xFULL?'\0':-1:>>>=a<:!!0X.1P1 ]
```

The first thing I notice is that we are using the ternary operator from the use of `?`. So the subexpression:

```
0xFULL ? '\0' : -1
```

is saying "if `0xFULL` is non-zero, return `'\0'`, otherwise `-1`. `0xFULL` is a hexadecimal literal with the *unsigned long-long suffix* - meaning it's a hexadecimal literal of type `unsigned long long`. That doesn't really matter though, because `0xF` can fit inside a regular integer.

Also, the ternary operator converts the types of the second and third terms to their common type. `'\0'` is then converted to `int`, which is just `0`.

The value of `0xF` is way bigger than zero, so it passes. The expression now becomes:

```
a[ 0 :>>>=a<:!!0X.1P1 ]
```

Next, `:>` is a [digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs). It is a construct that expands to `]`:

```
a[0 ]>>=a<:!!0X.1P1 ]
```

`>>=` is the signed right shift operator, we can space that out from `a` to make it clearer.

Moreover, `<:` is a digraph that expands to `[`:

```
a[0] >>= a[!!0X.1P1 ]
```

`0X.1P1` is a hexadecimal literal with an exponent. But no matter the value, the `!!` of anything that's non-zero is true. `0X.1P1` is `0.125` which is non-zero, so it becomes:

```
a[0] >>= a[true]
-> a[0] >>= a[1]
```

The `>>=` is the signed right shift operator. It changes the value of its left operand by shifting its bits forward by the value on the operator's right side. `10` in binary is `1010`. So here are the steps:

```
01010 >> 1 == 00101
00101 >> 1 == 00010
00010 >> 1 == 00001
00001 >> 1 == 00000
```

`>>=` returns the result of its operation, so as long as shifting `a[0]` remains non-zero for every time its bits are shifted right by one, the loop will continue. The fourth attempt is where `a[0]` becomes `0`, so the loop is never entered.

As a result, `?` is printed three times.

Comment: `:>` is a *digraph*, not a trigraph. It's not handled by the preprocessor, it's simply recognized as a token equivalent to `]`.

Comment: The ternary operator (`?:`) has a type that is the common type of the second and third terms.  The first term is always a conditional and has a type `bool`.  Since both second and third terms have type `int` the result of the ternary operation will be `int`, not `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @KeithThompson it could be handled by the preprocessor. The preprocessor has to know about digraphs because `#` and `##` have digraph forms; there's nothing stopping an implementation from translating digraphs to non-digraphs during the early translation phases

Comment: @MattMcNabb It's been a long time since I had to know this, but IIRC as a consequence of other requirements, digraphs have to stay in their digraph form until the point where pp-tokens are converted to tokens (right at the beginning of translation phase 7).

Comment: @Corey: The first operand of `?:` has scalar type; it needn't have type `bool` (which was only introduced to the language in 1999; `?:` is much older), and it's not converted to `bool`. Incidentally, `0xFULL` is of type `unsigned long long`, not `long long`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yes, the preprocessor has to know about digraphs, both because of `%:` and `%:%:` and because `#if` expressions can use them, but there's no reason for it to convert them. The standard describes digraphs as tokens that behave the same as what they're equivalent to.