# Single colons in arbitrary expressions?

Tags: c++, digraphs

I need to figure out what this obfuscated C++ code (written by someone else) does. I've figured pretty much everything, except one tricky part:

```
bool part1(char *flag)
{
    int *t = (int *) memfrob(flag, 8);

    unsigned int b[] = {3164519328, 2997125270};

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; b[i] = ~b[i], ++i);

    return !(0<:t:>-0<:b:>+1<:t:>-1<:b:>);
}
```

What is going on in the return statement of this function? I have no idea what these colons mean...

I've tried googling what does the colon operator in C++ do, but found only answers about class constructors and the conditional expression, which doesn't seem relevant to this problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm not sure about adding [digraphs] as a tag. OP doesn't know that the syntax is using that feature, and if they did, the question would be moot. OTOH, the tag *is* relevant, so perhaps it's good to add it?

Comment: @cigien - deobfuscation is irrelevant as a tag. And making the question easier to find in the future is not doing harm to the OP.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yeah, removing [deobfuscation] makes sense. And you're right, there's no *harm* in adding a tag that helps with searches. Got it, thanks.

Comment: duplicates: [What is this smiley-with-beard expression: `<:]{%>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15736282/995714), [`<:` and `:>` in obfuscated code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25495042/995714)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is making use of two-letter [alternative tokens](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative), also known as "digraphs". Specifically, `<:` is `[`, and `:>` is `]`.

So, syntax like `0<:t:>` is just `0[t]`, and since array subscripts can be swapped with the array identifier, this is just `t[0]`.

A great tool that can help with deobfuscating code is [cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/s/c2a3d2f3). As can be seen in the link, the code is just doing some arithmetic on the array values (ignore the `static_cast` for this example, it's not important for the purposes of understanding the transformation).

Comment: Furthermore, given that the program also uses the non-digraph symbols, the digraphs are presumably there for purpose of intentional obfuscation.

Comment: @eerorika Yeah, it's definitely meant for obfuscation. As the OP mentions, they got the obfuscated code from somewhere, possibly from a competition, or quiz, or something like that.