# How to set, clear a bit of a long long int number in C/C++?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I want to set bit in a `long long int` number on a 64 bit machine.
Example, i want to set bit at element 18 19, i use the following code:

```
A1 |= 1 << 2 * i;  // i = 9 , set bit 18 =1, A1 long long int
A1 &= ~(1 << 2 * i + 1); //clear bit 19 = 0
```

but it doesn't work. If i do it for `long int`, it works fine.

Comment: The shifted `1` should be `long long` too, so maybe `1LL`.

Comment: To set both bits 18 and 19 why not simply use e.g.  `A1 |= (1LL << 18 | 1LL << 19)`.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a vague description of a problem, inviting people to guess what the actual problem is. It would be better to post a complete program, which outputs an unexpected value, and state what the expected value is. See also [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Consider using `std::bitset`, which performs some safety checking in good debug compilers.

Comment: Related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809292/ull-suffix-on-a-numeric-literal)?

Comment: You should do what @Joachim or Neil suggested, because, as you have it written now, nobody would have the slightest clue what you're trying to accomplish without reading the comments. Even then, it's still unnecessarily obfuscated.

Comment: thanks pascal mcve-anatolyg Joachim. Joachim, because it in a loop, and I want to set a bit and clear a bit so I seperate 2 part to do and use "i". Do you have any ideal to set and clear it at the same time.

Comment: NeilKrik I can't use bitset because i set bit in CUDA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal `1` has type `int`, which is probably smaller than `long long`. You'll get undefined behaviour (typically a value of zero) if you shift by enough bits to overflow the `int` type; and the second line will (probably) clear any bits present in `A1` but not in an `int` value.

Use `1LL` to specify a `long long` type, or `decltype(A1)(1)` to specify a type that matches `A1`.

In general, it's usually best to use unsigned types (`unsigned long long` or perhaps `uint64_t` in this case) for bit-wrangling. Use `1ULL` to get a literal of type `unsigned long long`.