# Is there a limit of n bits when bit shifting?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, constexpr

While trying to come up with a scheme for a bitboard class, I decided use global compile time variables to represent key bit board configurations, ex. the initial position of all black rooks.

```
constexpr uint64_t BLACK_ROOK_INIT  = 0x1 | (0x1 << 56);
```

However I am getting compiler errors.  The compiler appears to be treating this value as a 32 bit value and type casting or adding additional 0's does not seem to make a difference.  The type definition is from .

As soon as I drop constexp from this expression it compiles, however still produces the equivalent warning. Why is this happening? I thought it might be a limitation of the pre-processor, but the problem persists without constexp.

```
chess.cpp:16:64: error: right operand of shift expression ‘(1 << 56)’ is >= than the precision of the left operand [-fpermissive]
```

FYI, this also does not compile

```
constexpr int64_t BLACK_ROOK_INIT = (int64_t)0x1 | (int64_t)(0x1 << 32);
```

Comment: `1` *is* an `int`. You could use `uint64_t(1)` to get a wider value.

Comment: This still doesn't compile.  I'll append above to demonstrate.

Comment: 1 is int. The conversion to int64_t happens *after* the shift. You want 1LL.

Comment: You should cast first and shift later, `(int64_t(1) << 32)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  constexpr uint64_t BLACK_ROOK_INIT  = 0x1ULL | (0x1ULL << 56);
  std::cout<<BLACK_ROOK_INIT<<std::endl;
}
```

Your `0x1` value is, by default, an `int`, which is usually implemented as a 32-bit integer.

The suffixes are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34931381/752843). If they make you a bit uncomfortable, as they do me, you can cast as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  constexpr uint64_t BLACK_ROOK_INIT  = (uint64_t)(0x1) | ((uint64_t)(0x1) << 56);
  std::cout<<BLACK_ROOK_INIT<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here 1 is int and after shifting it crosses the limit of int.
so firstly we need to convert int to long long int(a/c to your requirements)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;                
    ll l=(long long int)1<<n;
    cout<<l<<endl;
}
```