# Why can't UInt64 variable contain a value larger than UInt32::Max?

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I have two variables **a** and **b** and are declared and assigned as follows:

```
UInt64 a = (UInt64)4294967295 * 3;
UInt64 b = 4294967295 * 3;
```

When I print them **a** contains 12884901885 and **b** contains 4294967295.

Why do I have to cast the number with UInt64 to store such a large value ?

Thanks

Comment: Use LL suffix on the numbers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809292/ull-suffix-on-a-numeric-literal

Comment: The result of the multiplication is the type of the operands, (or `int`).

Comment: Are you familiar with the following nuance: `float x = 1/2;` results in `x == 0.0`, while `float x = (float)1/2;` results in `x == 0.5`?

Comment: One thing you could do is type `auto b = 4294967295;`.  Hover over the b variable and it will tell you that it is a variable of `unsigned long`.  Which is a type that's big enough to represent that value, takes 32 bits of storage.  Multiply it by 3 and you have a value that no longer fits in 32 bits.  The wise men decided that this not something they have to warn you about.  Yes, not very wise, they didn't have a lot of memory back in the 1970s.

Answer (score 1):

you need to append 'ULL' (a.k.a. Unsigned Long Long) to the constant to indicate it should be considered to be a 64bit value.

```cpp
UInt64 b = 4294967295ULL * 3;
```

Comment: This explains how to *solve* the problem, but does not explain the *reason why* the original code doesn't work. You should expand on your answer accordingly.