# How do you format a (Signed) long long integer using printf?

Tags: c

How do you format a (Signed) long long int using printf?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    long long int num = 123456766666666890; //FYI: fits in 29 bits
    int RegularInteger = 4;
    printf("My number is %d bytes wide and its value is %d. A normal number is %d.\n", sizeof(num), num, RegularInteger);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
My number is 8 bytes wide and its value is 1917383562. A normal number is 4.
```

I am not getting desired output.

Comment: You may want to read this question and its answers: [ULL suffix on a numeric literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809292/ull-suffix-on-a-numeric-literal)

Comment: My compiler complains: `a.c:4:25: error: integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type
    long long int num = 1234567666666666666666890; //FYI: fits in 29 bits`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I changed the question a bit.

Comment: 123456766666666890 == 0x1B69B467248F38A requires more than 29 bits to represent!

Comment: You can use `%lld` depending on the compiler.

Comment: @SpirosGkogkas I am using online c compiler. Don't know about the rest https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ok, Sorry I am new., I have deleted those comments.

Comment: @SpirosGkogkas Are there any non-C99 compilers that support `long long int` but do not use `%lld` as the corresponding printf/scanf specifier?

Comment: @IanAbbott avr-gcc for example, many stdlib nano implementations (ARM, RISC-V) etc etc

Comment: @IanAbbott compiler does not care about formats, implementation in the standard library does

Comment: @0___________ "compiler does not care about formats, implementation in the standard library does" is not completely true these days.

Comment: @IanAbbott if you write about compiler printf format check then yes - compiler will checkit, consider OK, no warning, but the implementation will not print it correctly. BTW the same situation is with floats. Embedded libraries do not print floats by default.

Comment: @0___________ The compiler could also optimize based on the format string, such as replacing `printf("%s\n", string);` with `puts(string);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott it is not related to the topic

Answer (score 3):

Enable all warnings, A good compiler will warn about mis-matched specifiers and save time.

**Use matching specifiers.**

With C99 or later

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  long long int num = 123456766666666890; // A 57 bit number
  int RegularInteger = 4;

  // printf("My number is %d bytes wide",  sizeof(num));
  printf("My number is %zu bytes wide",  sizeof(num));

  // printf("and its value is %d.", num);
  printf("and its value is %lld.", num);

  printf(" A normal number is %d.\n", RegularInteger);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    long long int num = 123456766666666890; //FYI: fits in 29 bits
    int RegularInteger = 4;
    printf("My number is %zu bytes wide and its value is %lld. A normal number is %d.\n", sizeof(num), num, RegularInteger);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eMvjGnr7Y

[Source of image](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

[image]

Comment: Any comment silent DV-ter

Comment: Not my DV (and any DV previously applied seems to have been removed), but this answer would be improved by some explanatory prose.